# WP8 Xml parser in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I've been trying to convert a downloaded xml string into Lists based on their element, but I can't seem to find a solution.
My goal is to get the artist name.

Here is an excerpt of the xml page:

```
<subsonic-response xmlns="http://subsonic.org/restapi" status="ok" version="1.10.2">
  <artists ignoredArticles="The El La Los Las Le Les">
      <index name="A">
         <artist id="15" name="A Tribe Called Quest" coverArt="ar-15"    albumCount="5"/>
         <artist id="2" name="A$AP Ferg" coverArt="ar-2" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="11" name="A$ap Mob" coverArt="ar-11" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="353" name="A$AP Rocky" coverArt="ar-353" albumCount="3"/>
         <artist id="382" name="A-1" coverArt="ar-382" albumCount="3"/>
         <artist id="9" name="A1 Bassline & Rusko" coverArt="ar-9" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="25" name="Aaliyah" coverArt="ar-25" albumCount="7"/>
         <artist id="1" name="Ab-Soul" coverArt="ar-1" albumCount="4"/>
         <artist id="50" name="Ace Hood" coverArt="ar-50" albumCount="18"/>
         <artist id="134" name="Adele" coverArt="ar-134" albumCount="4"/>
         <artist id="283" name="Aesop Rock & Del Tha Funky Homosapien" coverArt="ar-283" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="92" name="Afroman" coverArt="ar-92" albumCount="10"/>
         <artist id="280" name="Akinyele" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="421" name="Akira Kosemura" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="163" name="Akon" coverArt="ar-163" albumCount="20"/>
         <artist id="152" name="Akon, T-pain" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="106" name="All Saints" coverArt="ar-106" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="287" name="Almighty" coverArt="ar-287" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="176" name="Amanda Blank" coverArt="ar-176" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="56" name="ASIAN KUNG-FU GENERATION" coverArt="ar-56" albumCount="6"/>
         <artist id="374" name="Atmosphere" albumCount="11"/>
         <artist id="105" name="Attaca Pesante" coverArt="ar-105" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="190" name="Audio Bullys" coverArt="ar-190" albumCount="1"/>
         <artist id="44" name="August Alsina" coverArt="ar-44" albumCount="1"/>
     </index>
<index name="B">
```

Comment: "I can't seem to find a solution" - what have you tried so far? I'd use LINQ to XML, personally... have you tried that? What did the code look like, and what problems did you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my idea but you have to create list "names" before. Try this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("your xml file");
foreach (var elem in xDoc.Document.Descendants("artist"))
{
    names.Add(elem.Attribute("name").Value);
}
```

Comment: this will go to the index element, and not the artist element

Comment: This answer was close but did not add any descendants. I found through some tinkering that each Descendant name is created with the name structure of              `"{http://subsonic.org/restapi} + Descendant.name".` It works now.